# Codeblocks on linux mint Process terminated with status -1

Tags: c++, linux, codeblocks, linux-mint

So i just installed code blocks on Lnux mint 19, but i have a problem.
I ran the usual hello world program, but got "Process terminated with status -1". The "build" part works, but when i hit the "run" i get that error. I have g++ installed and set as default compiler. Any idea?

Tried everything i could find on the internet. Added the rep, tried installing from both the software center and from the terminal, same result.

```
int main()
{
cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Process terminated with status -1

Comment: Did you install xterm properly?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, from the minimal amount of code you've posted, you're missing includes. 
If you're not missing includes, you're not telling your compiler where `cout` and `endl` are.

Your code **should** look like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;

    cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here's a brief explanation.

`#include <iostream>` Tells the preprocessor to load this header file in to your translation unit (CPP file), so you have all the forward-declarations required to use the different objects, functions, and other members of the STL.

`using std::cout` && `using std::endl`
These two pieces of code tell the compiler specifically which members of the `std` namespace you wish to use. 
I'd recommend using this method (even though it may seem tedious), rather than `using namespace std;`.
By `using` the entire namespace, you're polluting your global namespace in this case.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) for some more examples as to why you should avoid `using namespace`.

Answer (score 0):

Your default Linux terminal seems to be incompatible with the calling C function. Try to install a plain xterm additionally to your main terminal:

```
$ sudo apt install xterm
```

Try running your code now.

In case it doesn't help, you can also try to change your default terminal in codeblocks: Go to Settings > Environment > General Settings, and change the terminal to "gnome-terminal" for example.

If that fails, the actual X display error will be helpful for further troubleshooting:

```
$ tail -f ~/.xsession-errors
```

Try running your code now and check your terminal for the latest xsession error. Most likely, it will start with "Error setting file metadata:" There you may find the full error message.